# How to change Telegram channel name?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am using the Telethon library for python. How can I change Telegram channel name? Couldn't find this in documentation.

Comment: Documentation states if something is not present in API, you can call Telegram methods via low-level interface: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/full-api.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now, you have to use [Telethon's raw API](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/full-api.html). If we [search for "edit title"](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=edit%20title) we will find [`channels.editTitle`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/edit_title.html). Such page has the following automatically-generated example:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.EditTitleRequest(
        channel='username',
        title='My awesome title'
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

If you meant the username, [`channels.updateUsername`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/update_username.html) is the right one:

```
client(functions.channels.UpdateUsernameRequest(
    channel='old username',
    username='new username'
))
```

You can of course pass the channel ID or invite link instead of the username if it doesn't have one.